# Microsoft MessageCard: how to specify message priority

Tags: webhooks, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am using Teams web hooks to send messages in Microsoft from Postman. I want to use the available options to create important, urgent, or normal messages. How can I make a message urgent?

```
{
    "@type": "MessageCard",
    "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
    "themeColor": "d90b0b",
    "summary": "Fire Alarm Test",
    "sections": [
        {
            "activityTitle": "![TestImage](https://47a92947.ngrok.io/Content/Images/default.png)Fire Alarm Triggered",
            "activitySubtitle": "Alarm sent from MIC Wonderware",
            "activityImage": "https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/115-1157860_fire-icon-flame-hd-png-download.png",
            "facts": [
                {
                    "name": "Location",
                    "value": "ETC"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Time",
                    "value": "{{current_timestamp}}"
                }
            ],
            "markdown": true
        },
        {
            "title": "Images",
            "images": [
                {
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Josh - It does not support priority. For more details please check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html).

Comment: I read the documentation, but just wanted to confirm. I do understand the Microsoft Graph API for teams supports priority. Is there a way to create a card AND label it as Urgent using a `POST` request to the Graph API?